# Web automation using selenium and python - opening youtube video link

Tags: python, selenium, web, automation

I'm trying to open a youtube video. After navigating to the search results, I'm unable to open the desired link. it's not accepting the xpath for searchBaari. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/souravroy/Downloads/chromedriver-2')

driver.get('https://youtube.com')

searchbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]')

searchbox.send_keys('Baari')

searchButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-icon-legacy"]/yt-icon')

searchButton.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(4500)

searchBaari = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Baari Lyrics Translation"]/yt-formatted-string')

searchBaari.Click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any element with `@id="Baari Lyrics Translation"` on the page. Although there's a link with such title that partially matches. Try modifying the last couple of lines to use this locator:

```
searchBaari = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@title,"Baari Lyrics Translation")]')
searchBaari.click()
```

This should make it, I hope it helps. Good luck.

Comment: The id is `@id="video-title"`. But the problem with this is that it will open the first video of the search results.